# Merge tags [cursoradapter] and [android-cursoradapter]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request

The 107 questions tagged under [cursoradapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cursoradapter) are all tagged [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android). I propose that we merge these two tags together.

---

## Before:

[cursoradapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cursoradapter) **x 107**

[android-cursoradapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-cursoradapter) **x 5**

## After:

[android-cursoradapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-cursoradapter) **x 112**

Comment: Is [android] the only kind of [cursoradapter]?

Comment: AFAIK, yes. But even if it wasn't, all of the questions tagged under "cursoradapter" currently are all android-related (I checked manually... there are only ~100 of them). I think the best solution would be to merge the tags, but **not** make "cursoradapter" a synonym for "android-cursoradapter" (in case someone makes a non-Android related "cursoradapter" or something). But as of right now, I think we should merge all of the (clearly Android-related) "cursoradapter" questions with "android-cursoradapter" so that low rep users will make use of the "android-cursoradapter" instead.

Comment: By the way, I made a similar request concerning "cursorloader" vs. "android-cursorloader" [**here**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/137410/181816) (in case you didn't see it).

Comment: These tags follow a pattern similar to tags such as [android-intent] and [android-activity].  Are there any other tags that need similar treatment?

Comment: Yes, but a lot of them are more difficult to merge (for example `[listview] and [android-listview]` can't be merged w/o some additional thought since some of the questions might be asking about the .NET listview). I do have a few others though: (1) **`[linearlayout] and [android-linearlayout]`**, (2) **`[actionbar] and [android-actionbar]`**, (3) **`[contentresolver] and [android-contentresolver]`**, (4) **`[fragmentactivity] and [android-fragmentactivity]`**. It should be pretty easy to confirm that these four merges won't cause any conflicts... I believe they are all unique to android.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, and I'm sure there are others too... I'll try and cool off with the tag merges for now though, I don't want to start pissing off the moderators :P

Comment: @RobertHarvey, and if you are bored tonight, you might also want to consider (5) `[tabhost] and [android-tabhost]`, (6) `[context] and [android-context]`, (7) `[arrayadapter] and [android-arrayadapter]`. I didn't confirm any of these though... when I suggested the `CursorAdapter/android-CursorAdapter` merge, I had previously checked to make sure they were all android related. I am pretty sure that `arrayadapter` and `tabhost` are unique to android though. Not 100% sure about `context` though. OK, I'll stop spamming you now :).

Comment: I've done them all except [listview] and [context], which will need to be disambiguated first.

Comment: awesome! no more merge requests from me for a while now :). thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Completed (posting this wiki answer to get the question off the unanswered page, please upvote).